# Can anyone explain why the maximum value of a concatenation between two arrays is so much higher than the max value in either single array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, netcdf

I have the following two datasets - both from netCDF files:

```
ds1 = observed_1979_01
ds2 = observed_1979_02
```

I want to extract the variable labelled 'swvl1' from both datasets, and I do this by:

```
m = ds1.variables['swvl1'][0,:,:]
n = ds2.variables['swvl1'][0,:,:]
```

I want to concantenate these two arrays together, which I do using np.dstack (though the same problem outlined here occurs with np.concatenate as well), such like:

```
d = np.dstack((m,n))
```

Now if I look at the maximum value in either array, I get that:

```
max_m = 0.76293164
max_n = 0.76335037
```

However, the max value f the concatenated arrays is:

```
max_d = 9.96921e+36
```

Why is this happening? I believe something must be going massively wrong in the concatenating of the two arrays to give a different maximum value, but I can't figure out what it is. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can this be reproduced without a dataset that only you have? (A good [mre] is something someone can copy/paste without changes to run and see the problem themselves, also making it easy to test and verify proposed fixes; if it can be reproduced with a dataset small enough to hardcode in the question, that would be ideal).

Comment: I suspect a `dtype` issue

Comment: I can't see any way to provide a minimal reproducible example I'm afraid as I have only encountered this problem with this specific dataset that I have. I know this isn't ideal but I can't see any way round it

Comment: @hpaulj what does that mean? how would I fix it?

Comment: First look at `m.dtype` etc.  We can't 'fix' something without first identifying the problem.  You have the data, we don't.  So we can only give advice based on what you tell us.

Comment: When I type 'm.dtype' it returns the following error message: TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not callable

Comment: Did you type `m.dtype` or `m.dtype()`?

Comment: apologies, it was m.dtype()

Comment: I have now tried it with m.dtype and it returns dtype('float32')

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value 9.96921e+36 is identical to the default _FillValue, which could indicate that your arrays contain uninitialized values before (and after) they are concatenated. Be sure all values are initialized to valid values before computing the maximum, and/or give the routine that computes the maximum the value 9.96921e+36 as the missing value to ignore.

Responding to question in comment below:

Yes. Uninitialized in this context means that the variable was defined and space allocated on disk to hold its values, however, no values were ever written. By default in netCDF, unwritten values appear as 9.96921e+36 when read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by initialized? How would I achieve that?

Comment: Looking at it, once concatenated, all values in the array are 9.969...e+36, would this be because of the same unitialized problem?